# My resultset is always returning false

Tags: java

I have written the following code:

```
String username=request.getParameter("username");
System.out.println(""+username);
String password=request.getParameter("password");
System.out.println(""+password);
Connection con=getConnection.getConnectionBuilder();
System.out.println("Inside");
PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("Select password from users where username=? ");
pstmt.setString(1, "username");

ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();

try
{
 System.out.println(""+rs.next());
    while(rs.next())
 {
    String pass=rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println(""+pass);
    if(pass.equals("password"))
    {
        out.print("Welcome back"+username);
    }
    else
    {
        out.print("Wrong username/password combination");
    }
}


}    

    catch(Exception e)
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
pstmt.close(); 
con.close();
```

My `rs.next()` part is always getting evaluated to `false`. How come is it happening so?

Comment: Your query is not returning anything, have you ran the query against the db to see if the record exist?

Comment: Even if this is a learning exercise, **do not do this**! Storing passwords in plain text is wrong no matter what.

Comment: You should also never output said password to the console/server log either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't call `rs.next()` twice :

```
 System.out.println(""+rs.next());
    while(rs.next())
```

You are moving the iterator each time you call it.

So if your query returns one row, the first `rs.next()` moves the iterator to point to that row, but the second `rs.next()` returns false and you never enter the `while` loop.

Removing the `System.out.println(""+rs.next());` line should help solve your problem.

In addition, you are searching for a username called "username", which probably doesn't exist, and comparing the returned password to "password", which is probably wrong.

Fixing all these problems would give you this code :

```
pstmt.setString(1, username);
ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();

try {
  while(rs.next()) {
    String pass=rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println(""+pass);
    if(pass.equals(password)) {
        out.print("Welcome back"+username);
    } else {
        out.print("Wrong username/password combination");
    }
  }
}     
catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are setting username to the string "username".

Try using your variable: `pstmt.setString(1, username);`

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `rs.next()` twice, moving the row iterator each time.

You might want to omit the `println()` which effectively "eats" your first (and only apparently) row.

Also, as @dasblinkenlight states in his comment - don't store passwords in cleartext. Just ask Target, Adobe and other why not...

Cheers,